# In this MySQL statement written in PHP, what is it meaning of ":"

Tags: php, mysql

hi i was working on a script to add some plugins 
but in a mysql statement i did not understand some characters 
i read mysql manual but i did not get it again 
can any one explain me what is :1 refers to or :3 
and is it meaning of :
thanks

```
else { // -------------------------------------------------------- user/all
        $conditions = '';
        if( !empty($this->user) ) {
            $conditions .= ' AND i.user = :3';
        }

        $this->thumbs = DB::query(
            'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                i.logged, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.logged) AS loggedTS,
                i.keyword, i.thumb, i.score, i.votes,
                u.name AS userName
            FROM '.TABLE_IMAGES.' i
            LEFT JOIN '.TABLE_USERS.' u
                ON u.id = i.user
            WHERE 1 '.$conditions.'
            ORDER BY i.id DESC
            LIMIT :1, :2',

            $this->page * $this->thumbsPerPage,
            $this->thumbsPerPage,
            $this->user['id']
        );
    }
```

Comment: What language is this? Where does DB::query come from? Looks like parameter substitution.

Comment: This doesn't look much like `mysql`. However, I think the `:1`,`:2` and `:3:` are placeholders in a prepared statement that variables will be bound to to create the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not technically part of the SQL. That's a parameterized field. It refers to the secondary arguments passed to `DB::query`, and presumably allows you to safely pass user input into the query without the risk of SQL injection.

In order:

`:1` corresponds to `$this->page * $this->thumbsPerPage`

`:2` corresponds to `$this->thumbsPerPage`

`:3` corresponds to `$this->user['id']`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `:2` refers to the third argument given to the function, `$this->thumbsPerPage`, and `:3` refers to `$this->user['id']`. It's not a MySQL thing, just something that the `DB::query` function does.

Comment: and :3 is referring to the 4.th argument is that right . do i add argument at the end of statement with comas

Answer (score 0):

The colon is sometimes used to specify that the value should be replaced by a parameter. Note that the first argument to DB::query() is the string query and the next three are all parameters. Those parameters get placed into the SQL string using the :NUMBER specified format.

In your example, :3 would be replaced with $this->user['id'] since it is the third parameter passed into the query.

However, in parameterized SQL queries a ? is typically used for this purpose. Check the documentation on the DB connection library you are using to ensure that this is the proper parameter syntax.